# How to filter a list into a new list of its same type using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have two models, one is an item and the other is a list of those items. Using `LINQ`. A service returns all of the items, I'd like a second method to further filter those items based on their Id.

```
public class MyItem {
    public string Id;
    public string Description;
}

public class MyItems {
    public List<MyItem> ItemsList
}

public MyItems GetAllItems()
{
    return someServiceThatReturnsMyItems()
}

public MyItems GetItemsById(string[] itemIds)
{
    return GetAllItems().ItemsList.Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x .Id)).ToList();
}
```

I would like `getItemsById` to return a filtered collection of `MyItems`. I have tried selecting into a new list however the types never match, I always have a single MyItem returned.

I can do something like this:

```
return new MyItems()
{
    ItemsList = GetAllItems().ItemsList.Where(x => insuredIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList()
};
```

Is it possible to do in a single line of LINQ, or do I have this right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) similar to the `ToList` method that does this, as follows:

```cs
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static MyItems ToMyItems(this IEnumerable<MyItem> source)
    {
        return new MyItems { ItemsList = source.ToList() };
    }
}
```

Your `GetItemsById` method then becomes as follows:

```cs
public MyItems GetItemsById(string[] itemIds)
{
    return GetAllItems().ItemsList.Where(x => itemIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToMyItems();
}
```